# Sections $s$ such that "${s(x) \neq 0 }$ is affine" is a vector subspace

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme, $\mathcal{L}$ be a line bundle on $X$.

For section $s \in H^0 (X, \mathcal{L})$ denote by $X_s$ an open subscheme of $X$ defined by $s \neq 0$.

Finally denote by $A =  \{ s \in H^0 ( X, \mathcal{L} )$ such that $X_s$ is affine}.

**Question** Why $A$ is a vector subspace of $H^0 (X, \mathcal{L})$ ?

Comment: @evgeny: I've noticed that you are retagging many old questions with a newly created tag. This is not OK, since most of those questions have been already answered, and therefore no longer benefit from retagging. Therefore, please stop this unnecessary editing and let your new tag be used only in future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a vector space structure, you need a field, so I guess $X$ is a scheme over some field. But this does not really touch us, since $A$ is obviously closed under scalar multiplication. The interesting part is closedness under addition.

Use Exercise 2.17 in Hartshorne:

> A scheme $S$ is affine if and only if there is a finite set of global
>   sections $f_1, \dotsc, f_r \in H^0(S,\mathcal O_S)$, that generate the
>   unit ideal and each $S_{f_i}$ is affine.

Let $s,t \in H^0(X,\mathcal L)$ be global sections, such that $X_s$ and $X_t$ are affine.

Note that $$\mathcal O_{X|X_{s+t}} \xrightarrow{\cong} \mathcal L_{|X_{s+t}}, 1 \mapsto s+t$$, hence the ideal generated by $s_{|X_{s+t}}$ and $t_{|X_{s+t}}$ is the unit ideal in $H^0(X_{s+t},\mathcal O_{X|X_{s+t}})$.

We are left to show that $(X_{s+t})_s = X_s \cap X_{s+t}$ is affine ($(X_{s+t})_t$ is of course dealt with the same way). But this is clear, since we have $(X_{s+t})_s = X_s \cap X_{s+t}=(X_{s})_{s+t}$ and the latter is a principal open subscheme of an affine scheme, hence affine.